# Ajax и wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Можно ли сделать свой файл обработчик ajax, например test.php, который будет лежать в папке с темой, рядом с footer.php, header.php например и оттуда отрабатывать уже запросы. Или только возможно в function.php это делать, через add_action()?

Comment: Можно, только зачем?

Comment: ajax - это возможность js, значит не test.php, а test.js, в котором будет функция отправки подключенная в вашему шаблону